# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo 2 métodos que me retornan datos, ambos los ordeno con ->orderBy('id', 'ASC'), sin embargo, uno me da error y el otro no.

Este es el que me genera error (El error es `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.`):

```
public function getServiceProviderCompanies () {

    $serviceProviderCompanies = ServiceProviderCompany::all('id', 'name')
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    return $serviceProviderCompanies;
}
```

El que me funciona bien es este:

```
public function getParking () {
    $parking = Property::whereHas('propertyType', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'parking lot');
    })
    ->with('propertyType', 'location')
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    return $parking;
}
```

Honestamente no comprendo mucho las diferencias entre cada uno,ya que al final ambos tienen el método get(), por que funcionan diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No puedes usar el método `orderBy()` junto al método `all()` pues este último (*que se encuentra dentro de la clase `Model`*) nos retorna a *`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]`* y como puedes observar dicho método no existe dentro de esa clase
- Por cierto en este caso no hace falta especificar si el ordenamiento es *asc* pues este es el valor que *por default* tiene el método declarado como puedes observar en la declaración del mismo:

  ```
  public function orderBy($column, $direction = 'asc')
  ```
- En cambio para lograr lo que deseas basta que modifiques tu consulta de este modo debido al hecho que [*cada modelo de Eloquent sirve como un query builder*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries):

  ```
  $serviceProviderCompanies = ServiceProviderCompany::select('id', 'name')
                                                   ->orderBy('id')
                                                   ->get();
  ```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias, pero, por que no se puede usar all y orderBy juntos?

Answer (score 0):

El método `all` retorna toda la data que tienes dentro de tu tabla en forma de una `collection`. Por tanto lo que puedes hacer es utilizar los metodos que ofrece la libreria en este caso el `sortBy`. (te dejo el [link aca](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby) )

Por otro lado si quieres es traer la data desde la base de datos ya ordenada puedes hacer esto

```
$results = ServiceProviderCompany::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```